# Make a change to date fields automatically in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 date fields and I want to update the date automatically.
The code won't work until I update the updated field by myself.
How can I make it update itself (updated fields) automatically?

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
('P', 'Paid'),
('U', 'UNPAID'),
)

status = models.CharField(
    max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() )
expiry = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30) )

def save(self):
    if(self.expiry >= self.updated):
        self.status = default = "P"
    else:
        self.status = default = "U"
        self.expiry = default=self.updated+timedelta(days=1)
    
    super(Users, self).save()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? Do you want this code to be executed on  the schedule basis?

Comment: @d2718nis no the codes won't works till i open the user page and update the date (the updated field ) on my own . i wanted to do that  automatically so if today is 21-2 and after month it's 21-3 it will change the status automatically (depending on the expiry date ) it's not changing it till i update the filed manually

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTimeField` have a [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) property, that will set the field to the current date every time the object is saved.

The main question is what event should trigger the save action. For example you can improve your view, so that every time someone visit the page, your model would update as well as desired DateTimeField. On the other hand you may want this happen on the schedule basis, so you should use something like [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [Huey](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html).

Comment: it looks like i am forced to use celery. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have two options.

1. Make some code that will be executed periodically that will update the status based on current date.
2. Do not store status in the database at all. If it can depend only from `expiry` field it can be a computed `property`

P.S.

It's not related to what you are asking but I have a suggestion for you. Never ever use the direct result from `datetime.now()` as default value for `DateTimeField`. It's misleading for you and it's not the same as what you want to achieve. `datetime.now` will be executed at import time (when the server starts) and will stay the same until next restart.
If you want the default value to be the exact time when the record was created then `default` value need to be a function (which will be executed every time) and not the result of the function.
This means that `updated` need to be `DateTimeFiled(default=datetime.now)` (without the brackets).

This logic is more like for a field called `created_at` or `date_created` and not `updated` but this is your logic.